# How to use Create Unique with Cypher

Tags: neo4j, cypher, spring-data-neo4j

My target is to create node + set new property to it in case not exists

if it's exist I just want to update it's property

Tried this:

```
MATCH (user:C9 {userId:'44'})
CREATE UNIQUE (user{timestamp:'1111'})
RETURN user
```

*in case the node with the property userId=44 already existed I just want to set it's property into 1111 else just create it and set it.

error I am getting:

```
user already declared (line 2, column 16 (offset: 46))
"CREATE UNIQUE (user{timestamp:'1111'})"
```

should I switch to Merge or?

thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, you should use the `MERGE` statement.

```
MERGE (user:C9 {userId:'44'})
// you can set some initial properties when the node is created if required
//ON CREATE SET user.propertykey = 'propertyvalue' 
ON MATCH SET user.timestamp = '1111'
RETURN user
```

You mention unique constraints - I assume you have one set up. You definitely should do to prevent duplicate nodes being created. It will also create a schema index to improve the performance of your node lookup. If you do not yet have a unique constraint then it can be created like so

```
CREATE CONSTRAINT ON (u:C9) ASSERT u.userId IS UNIQUE
```

See the [Neo4j MERGE documentation](http://neo4j.com/docs/stable/query-merge.html).

Finally, to understand what is going on in your query let's have a quick look line by line.

```
MATCH (user:C9 { userId:'44' })
```

This matches the node with label `:C9` that has a `userId` property with value `44` and assigns it the identifier `user`.

```
CREATE UNIQUE (user{timestamp:'1111'})
```

This line is simply trying to create a new node with no label and a property `timestamp` with value `'1111'`. The exception you are seeing is a result of you using the same `user` identifier that has already been used in the first line. However, this is not a supported way to use `CREATE UNIQUE` as it requires a match first and will then create bits of the pattern that does not exist. The upside of this is that it is stopping this unwanted node `(user{timestamp:'1111'})` being created in the graph.

```
RETURN user
```

This line is pretty self explanatory and is not being reached.

**EDIT**
There seems to be some confusion surrounding `CREATE UNIQUE` and when it should be used. This query

```
CREATE UNIQUE (user:C9 {timestamp:'1111'})
```

will fail with the message

> > This pattern is not supported for CREATE UNIQUE

To use `CREATE UNIQUE` you would first match an existing node and then use that to create a unique pattern in the graph. So to create a relationship from `user` to a second node you would use

```
MATCH (user:C9 { userId: '44' }
CREATE UNIQUE (user)-[r:FOO]-(bar)
RETURN r
```

If there is no relationships of type `FOO` from `user` then a new node will be created to represent `bar` and relationship of type `:FOO` will be created between them. Conversely, if the `MATCH` statement does not make a match then no nodes or relationships will be created.

Comment: thx for your response. but why u using MERGE instead of create unique which defining this exact requirement ?

Comment: You said that if the node already exists you just want to set the property. `CREATE UNIQUE` will always try and create a node if there is not an exact match. `MERGE` will either create a node or match an existing one. You can then take different actions depending if the statement creates or matches.

Comment: @rayman I have edited my answer in an attempt to make it clearer. Does this help? You should definitely be using MERGE to satisfy your requirement.